# validating internet address in javascript

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i validate a url in javascript using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420896/how-can-i-validate-a-url-in-javascript-using-regular-expression)

I want to validate whether user input a valid internet adress like
www.hotmail.com
http://www.abc.com.pk

Comment: Define "valid." Does the address have to be FORMATTED correctly (so that www.example is invalid, but www.example.co.uk is valid)? Or does it have to actually BE valid (so that www.this-domain-is-not-actually-registered.com is invalid)? If it has to BE valid, for what purpose? Must there be a website there? Or is it okay if the domain has valid and working MX records but no website?

Comment: **Possible duplicate:** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1420896/how-can-i-validate-a-url-in-javascript-using-regular-expression

Comment: And define "Internet address". Do you mean an "http URI"? FQDN? (You give examples both of these.) An email address is ad much an "internet address" as either of those examples (as are many other things).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the js function:

```
function validateString(regexPattern, testString) {
 var regexObj = new RegExp(regexPattern);
 return regexObj.test(testString);
}
```

Finding the regex for URLs is just a matter of typing it in google. [Here's a good one](http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View2D3B0109-C1B2-4B4E-BFFD-E8088CBC85FD.htm) I've used before.

Comment: Omg, why not just do `if (/[somepattern]/i.test(url)) {...}`?

Comment: cause I like if(validatestring("regex","test")){} better! :)