# (JQuery/PHP) Validating data before submit

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, input

What's the best approach for validating input (form) data right after it's typed?

My idea is having a DIV right next to the input, this div is where we'll see a message saying whether data is valid or not, like:

```
Your name:
<input type="text">
<div id="data-validation"></div>

<script>
$("input").change(function(){
    $("#data-validation").load("data-validation.php?input="+$(this).val());
});
</script>

//data-validation.php
<?php
$input = $_GET["input"];
if(strlen($input) < 3)
    echo "Name must have at least 3 characters.";
?>
```

And PHP takes care of validating and displaying data.

I'm afraid there's a much better way for doing this, I'd like to know what's the best way to do this.

Comment: For validation at the "as they type" stage, if your validation rules are just about number of characters, format and/or data types I'd suggest you do it all in JavaScript. If you want to check against a database for some reason (e.g., validating street addresses or something) _then_ you could use Ajax/PHP similar to your example. Note that the `.change()` event in your sample will never be triggered since you've set it up on the div rather than the input. Also, note that you should _always_ (re)validate _all_ the fields in your PHP once the form is actually submitted.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I also will have to revalidate all data after its been submited, otherwise it would be very easy to hack. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Validation by JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5067410/validation-by-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely!

You can do most of your string checks from the JavaScript end to prevent unnecessary calls to the server. You still keep your PHP checks but now you want to duplicate them to the JavaScript end, for example:

```
$("#data-validation").change(function(){
    if($(this).val().length >= 3) {
       $(this).load("data-validation.php?input="+$(this).val());
    } else {
       alert("Name must have at least 3 characters.");
    }
});
```

If you have several checks, instead of checking the length, check against a function that does a series of tasks on the JavaScript end. You want to make sure your PHP does the same thing though, as a browser JavaScript can easily by bypassed. You want to optimize by doing less calls to the server, and utilize more local resources.

Comment: I understand your point. But I tried to make my example as simple as possible, I'll actually have to do some server-side validation too, because these data will be saved on MySQL, and there can't be duplicate data, so yeah, javascript alone won't do the job. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I highly recommend using [jQuery Validate](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) you still need to validate on php side to but this will save you a ton of work on the UI / jQuery side of things